# Regex replace string which is before or after two different string

Tags: python, regex

I have this string (html):

```
html = 'x<sub>i</sub> - y<sub>i)<sub>2</sub>'
```

I would like to convert this html string to latex in a robust way. Let me explain:

1. `<sub>SOMETHING</sub>` -> converted to `_{SOMETHING}`

I already know how to do that:

```
latex = re.sub(r'<sub>(.*?)</sub>',r'_{\1} ', html)
```

2. Sometimes the first part `<sub>` or its closing tag is missing, like in the example string. In that case, the output should still be correct.

So how I was thinking of doing it is: After running 1, I take the string after `<sub>` and anything before `</sub>` with `_{SOMETHING}`

```
text = re.sub(r'<sub>(.*?)</sub>',r'_{\1} ', html)
print(text)
# if missing part:
text = re.sub(r'<sub>(.*?)',r'_{\1} ', text)
print(text)
latex  = re.sub(r'(.*?)</sub>',r'_{\1} ', text)
```

… but I get:

```
x_{i}  - y_{i)<sub>2} 
x_{i}  - y_{i)_{} 2} 
x_{i}  - y_{i)_{} 2}
```

What I would like to get:

```
x_{i}  - y_{i})_{2}
```

Comment: Sounds like `text = text.replace('<sub>', '_{').replace('</sub>', '}')` should do.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for your comment. When I try your command I get: `x_{i} - y_{i)_{2}`. It's almost good, but there is a missing `}`bracket after the second  `i`.

Comment: How can you describe the place where the `}` is missing? It is not possible without more detailed requirements.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That is very true. Sorry, yes, you are completely right.

Comment: My top comment solution is based on an assumption you have texts that are segmented into different parts, and the corresponding `</sub>` may reside in the next segment, so it should suffice to just replace them one by one separately (this is a very common scenario in localization). That means you do not need to make any guess work. If it is not your case, you should explain the tagged text format or context the text appears in, else, the "regular" language is of no help.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for your explanation. Upon second reflection, this is actually exactly my case. Can you post your comment as an answer, such that I can accept it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have texts that are segmented into different parts, the corresponding `<sub>` / `</sub>` tags may reside in the adjoining segments, so it should suffice to just replace them one by one separately, and you do not need to make any guess work.

Just use

```
text = text.replace('<sub>', '_{').replace('</sub>', '}')
```

to replace each `<sub>` with `_{` and `</sub>` with `}` in any context.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use greedy regexes (i.e. without `?`) for the unmatched tags, otherwise you'll always get zero-width matches.

```
>>> text = '1<sub>2'
>>> re.sub(r'<sub>(.*)', r'_{\1} ', text)
'1_{2} '
```

BTW while figuring this out, I noticed you can put the second two regexes together like this:

```
re.sub(r'<sub>(.*)|(.*)</sub>', r'_{\1\2} ', text)
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. I get: `_{x<sub>i</sub> - y<sub>i)<sub>2}`

Comment: @henry Yes, you need to replace the matched tags first, *then* run my regex to replace the unmatched tags. But don't worry about it anymore, since Wiktor's answer is better for your case.